# Upload a configuration/deployment on iothub using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

**What I want:**

To upload a **[configuration/deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMKb5.png)** (not directly on device) in iothub using .NET.

**The problem**

I am getting a badrequest error when using the API.

[image: badrequest]

My Main:

```
var iotHubName = "[iothubname].azure-devices.net";
var policyName = "iothubowner";
var key = "[iothubownerkey]";
var token = ConstructToken(iotHubName, policyName, key);
var result = DeployConfiguration(iotHubName, token);
Console.WriteLine($"Press a key to exit {result}");
```

My API post:

```
private static string DeployConfiguration(string iotHubName, string token)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

        var body = File.ReadAllText("deloyment.manifest.json");
        var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var restUriPut = $"https://{iotHubName}/configurations/configid?api-version=2020-05-31-preview";

        using var resultPut = client.PutAsync(restUriPut, stringContent).Result;

        return resultPut.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
```

I am creating my token using ConstructToken from this tutorial: **[Click here](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/deploy-azure-iot-edge-deployment-manifest-programmatically/)** (this tutorial contains how to make a token and how to upload a deployment directly on a device)

My deloyment.manifest.json (this includes OPC Publisher module and setup):

```
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.1",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {}
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "env": {
              "SendRuntimeQualityTelemetry": {
                "value": false
              }
            },
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4"
            },
            "type": "docker"
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"443/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"443\"}],\"5671/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"5671\"}],\"8883/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8883\"}]}}}"
            },
            "status": "running",
            "type": "docker"
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "OPCPublisher": {
            "env": {
              "ApplicationCertificateSubjectName": {
                "value": "C=US,L = Redmond,O=Contoso Inc.,OU=Contoso IT Security,CN=opcpublisher,DC=victor"
              },
              "ApplicationName": {
                "value": "opcpublisher"
              },
              "Test": {
                "value": "true"
              }
            },
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/iotedge/opc-publisher:latest",
              "createOptions": "{\"Hostname\":\"opcpublisher\",\"Cmd\":[\"-c\",\"--PkiRootPath=/mount/pki\",\"--pf=/mount/published_nodes.json\",\"--lf=/mount/publisher.log\",\"--mm=PubSub\",\"--me=Json\",\"--fd=false\",\"--bs=100\",\"--bi=1000\",\"--di=20\",\"--aa\"],\"HostConfig\":{\"Mounts\":[{\"Type\":\"bind\",\"Source\":\"/opcpublisher\",\"Target\":\"/mount\"}]}}"
            },
            "status": "running",
            "type": "docker"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.1",
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        },
        "routes": {
          "route": {
            "route": "FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OPCPublisher": {
      "properties.desired": {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

To share knowledge I will answer my own question since I already figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the required tags into your JSON file to make sure it has all the necessary items. You can find them **[HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/configuration/create-or-update)**

Make sure it has another {} around it. Make what you have now `"content":` and add

```
,
  "etag": {},
  "id": "configid",
  "priority": 100,
  "targetCondition": "tags.customtag='mydevice'"
```

after closing the content

Make sure `id` in the json and `var restUriPut = $"https://{iotHubName}/configurations/configid?api-version=2020-05-31-preview";` is the same (`configid`)

---

Example (bottom of the file):

```
{
  "content": {
    "modulesContent": {
      "$edgeAgent": {
        "properties.desired": {
          "schemaVersion": "1.1",
          "runtime": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {}
          },
          "systemModules": {
            "edgeAgent": {
              "env": {
                "SendRuntimeQualityTelemetry": {
                  "value": false
                }
              },
              "settings": {
                "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4"
              },
              "type": "docker"
            },
            "edgeHub": {
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4",
                "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"443/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"443\"}],\"5671/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"5671\"}],\"8883/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8883\"}]}}}"
              },
              "status": "running",
              "type": "docker"
            }
          },
          "modules": {
            "OPCPublisher": {
              "env": {
                "ApplicationCertificateSubjectName": {
                  "value": "C=US,L = Redmond,O=Contoso Inc.,OU=Contoso IT Security,CN=opcpublisher,DC=victor"
                },
                "ApplicationName": {
                  "value": "opcpublisher"
                },
                "Test": {
                  "value": "true"
                }
              },
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/iotedge/opc-publisher:latest",
                "createOptions": "{\"Hostname\":\"opcpublisher\",\"Cmd\":[\"-c\",\"--PkiRootPath=/mount/pki\",\"--pf=/mount/published_nodes.json\",\"--lf=/mount/publisher.log\",\"--mm=PubSub\",\"--me=Json\",\"--fd=false\",\"--bs=100\",\"--bi=1000\",\"--di=20\",\"--aa\"],\"HostConfig\":{\"Mounts\":[{\"Type\":\"bind\",\"Source\":\"/opcpublisher\",\"Target\":\"/mount\"}]}}"
              },
              "status": "running",
              "type": "docker"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "$edgeHub": {
        "properties.desired": {
          "schemaVersion": "1.1",
          "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
            "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
          },
          "routes": {
            "route": {
              "route": "FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "OPCPublisher": {
        "properties.desired": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "etag": {},
  "id": "configid",
  "priority": 100,
  "targetCondition": "tags.customtag='mydevice'"
}
```